# google's protocol buffer from c# to java - Protocol message tag had invalid wire type

Tags: c#, java, exception, protocol-buffers

I am creating a stream in C# and trying to read it in java, but I receive the error: "Protocol message tag had invalid wire type." when i read it in my java code the object created in c#.

**Details:** 
I started from an equal .proto file (see below) to create the correspondent .java file and .cs file (compiling using the protoc for java in version "protobuf-2.4.1" and the protobuf-csharp-port-2.4.1.473-full-binaries for c#).
I succeed to create the addressbook.java and the addressbook.cs.

The object is created in c# and written to a file using the following c# code:

```
[...]
byte[] bytes;

        //Create a builder to start building a message
        Person.Builder newContact = Person.CreateBuilder();

        //Set the primitive properties
        newContact.SetId(1)
                  .SetName("Foo")
                  .SetEmail("foo@bar");

        //Now add an item to a list (repeating) field
        newContact.AddPhone(
            //Create the child message inline
            Person.Types.PhoneNumber.CreateBuilder().SetNumber("555-1212").Build()
            );

        //Now build the final message:
        Person person = newContact.Build();


        newContact = null;
        using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //Save the person to a stream
            person.WriteTo(stream);
            bytes = stream.ToArray();


            //save this to a file (by me)
            ByteArrayToFile("personStreamFromC#", bytes);
[...]
```

I copy the created file "personStreamFromC#" to my java solution and try to read it using the following java code:

```
 AddressBook.Builder addressBook = AddressBook.newBuilder();

// Read the existing address book.
try {
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
    addressBook.mergeFrom(data);
  // Read the existing address book.
  AddressBook addressBookToReadFrom =
          AddressBook.parseFrom(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
  Print(addressBookToReadFrom);
}
```

But I get the following message:

> *Exception in thread "main" com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message
>   tag had invalid wire type.    at
>   com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidWireType(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:78)
>     at
>   com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:498)
>     at
>   com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$Builder.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessage.java:438)
>     at
>   com.example.tutorial.AddressBookProtos$Person$Builder.mergeFrom(AddressBookProtos.java:1034)
>     at
>   com.example.tutorial.AddressBookProtos$Person$Builder.mergeFrom(AddressBookProtos.java:1)
>     at
>   com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:275)
>     at
>   com.example.tutorial.AddressBookProtos$AddressBook$Builder.mergeFrom(AddressBookProtos.java:1715)
>     at
>   com.example.tutorial.AddressBookProtos$AddressBook$Builder.mergeFrom(AddressBookProtos.java:1)
>     at
>   com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:300)
>     at
>   com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:238)
>     at
>   com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:162)
>     at
>   com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:716)
>     at
>   com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:238)
>     at
>   com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:153)
>     at
>   com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:709)
>     at AddPerson.main(test.java:104)*

**Below the .proto file:** 
    package tutorial;
    message Person {
     required string name = 1;
     required int32 id = 2;        // Unique ID number for this person.
     optional string email = 3;

```
 enum PhoneType {
   MOBILE = 0;
   HOME = 1;
   WORK = 2;
 }

 message PhoneNumber {
   required string number = 1;
  optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
 }

 repeated PhoneNumber phone = 4;
 }

message AddressBook {
  repeated Person person = 1;
  }
```

Any ideas ??

Comment: you write `Person` object to file in C#, but then read `AddressBook` in Java, i don't think this is correct. try `Person.parseFrom(new FileInputStream(args[0]));`

Comment: @hoaz you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common mistake that can cause invalid wire-type errors (*especially* when using files) is: over-writing an existing file without truncating it. We can't see your ByteArrayToFile, but frankly `File.WriteAllBytes` may be an easier option. The problem is that if the new data is **smaller** than the original contents, any remaining extra bytes are essentially *garbage*.

My advice:

- check if you can deserialize it in c#; if you can't, the error is certainly in the file handling
- if it works in c#, check how you are getting the file to the java code: are you copying it around anywhere?
- and check you are using binary (not text) processing at all stages

Comment: 1) Using the File.WriteAllBytes didn't help, still same exception appearing in Java
2) Deserialization in c# works perfectly - see below:
3) I copy the file with a simple copy-paste from the bin directory in C# to the bin in Java.. should I do it differently ?

Comment: @MarcGravell this helped me a lot with a similar problem! Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

You write `Person` object to file in **C#**, but then read `AddressBook` in **Java**, I don't think this is correct. Try following in your Java code:

```
Person.parseFrom(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
```